# Axios how to send files inside objects without FormData?

Tags: javascript, axios

I have an object like this

```
  {
      data1: 1,
      data2: 2,
      file1: File,
      file2: File,
      file3: File,
      objects: [
          {name: "test1", info: "test", related: [1,2,3], files: [File, File, File]},
          {name: "test2", info: "test", related: [1,2,3], files: [File, File, File]},
          {name: "test3", info: "test", related: [1,2,3], files: [File, File, File]}
      ]
  }
```

I need to somehow send it to the backend with data and files (ideally keeping the object structure, but it will be fine if the files are sent in formdata alongside main object and I get them by keys that I will store in objects instead of the files themselves)